# What's the difference between a document fragment and creating a parent element?

Tags: javascript, html

This may be a really stupid question, but I seem to be missing the point of something fundamental again.

I understand how to create a document fragment, build a DOM subtree within it, and insert it into the DOM; and why this is useful.

I don't understand the difference between this and just creating the parent element needed, building the DOM subtree within that element, and then inserting it into the DOM.

What is the advantage of creating the fragment first? It seems as though a created element, before being added into the DOM, is almost the same as a fragment and both take place outside of the DOM.

Thank you.

Comment: because sometime you don't want to insert a single node into the dom but multiple sibling elements where a fragment is useful.

Comment: *"creating the parent element needed"* If you also need to create the parent, then no, there's no reason for a fragment. It's when you need multiple sibling insertions but *don't* need to create their parent that you'd use the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fragment allows you to create sibling elements that don't have a parent at the current point and time.

As you can see in this example we create two spans and add them to the already created div by using a fragment, so the spans are direct children.

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main')

let frag = document.createDocumentFragment()

let span1 = document.createElement('span')
span1.textContent = 'hello'
frag.appendChild(span1)

let span2 = document.createElement('span')
span2.textContent = 'world'
frag.appendChild(span2)

main.appendChild(frag)
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

This results in the following:

```html
<div id="main">
  <span>hello</span><span>world</span>
</div>
```

Now if we make a parent element and do the same, they are no longer direct children of the main div.

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main')

let div = document.createElement('div')

let span1 = document.createElement('span')
span1.textContent = 'hello'
div.appendChild(span1)

let span2 = document.createElement('span')
span2.textContent = 'world'
div.appendChild(span2)

main.appendChild(div)
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

When using a parent you get an output like this, as you can see you now have an extra div:

```
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <span>hello</span><span>world</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out this example to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

For the performance

> Because all of the nodes are inserted into the document at once, only one reflow and render is triggered instead of potentially one for each node inserted if they were inserted separately.

[Document​Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) from MDN

Comment: Thank you. I've read that.  The parent element I mentioned is still being added to the DOM only once after adding to it all its children elements, just as if the parent were the fragment.. So, I don't understand the performance difference relative to a fragment.